# adding JAR class path in UBUNTU

Tags: java, ubuntu, classpath

This is might be a common question but I am not able to add class path for a JAR file in UBUNTU. I have given below all the details I know:

java is located here:
the o/p of `which java` command is  - `/usr/bin/java`

```
sudo vim /etc/bash.bashrc  
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.3.24/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.3.24.jar
```

ps: downloads folder is directly under the root

```
sudo vim /etc/environment
CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/lib: /downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.3.24/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.3.24.jar:"
```

As you can see, I have added the class path in bashrc and etc/environment... but still I am getting an error while trying to run the `S3Sample.java` which comes with awssdk for java.

when I compile the java file, I get the following errors:

```
ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-03-31-91:/downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.3.24/samples/AmazonS3$ javac S3Sample.java

S3Sample.java:25: error: package com.amazonaws does not exist
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
```

Now, I clearly understand that the JAR file is not added to the class path and so I am not getting the error. I've also tried `javac` with the class path option - but it does not work :(

PS: JAVA home is set correctly as other java programs work properly.

Comment: What is the result of echo $CLASSPATH? And have you tried running with the -classpath option?

Comment: @Perception i tried this command - javac -cp '.:abc.jar' test.java... this works fine but I want to specify multiple JAR files instead of one. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 10):

To set the classpath, it is in most cases better to use the the `-cp` or `-classpath` argument when calling `javac` and `java`. It gives you more flexibility to use different classpaths for different java applications.

With the `-cp` and `-classpath` arguments your classpath can contain multiple jars and multiple locations separated with a `:` (colon)

```
javac -cp ".:/somewhere/A.jar:/elsewhere/B.jar" MyClass.java
java -cp ".:/somewhere/A.jar:/elsewhere/B.jar" MyClass
```

The classpath entry in the example sets the classpath to contain the current working directory (`.`), and the two jar files `A.jar` and `B.jar`.

If you want to use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable you can do

```
export CLASSPATH=".:/somewhere/A.jar:/elsewhere/B.jar"
javac MyClass.java
java MyClass
```